# Android compatibility issue on play store

Tags: android, google-play, version

I have uploaded my app on [google play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dexterous.genero15) and found that in

> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION

section it showing

> Requires Android 4.0.3 - 4.4

instead of 4.0.3 and up

My build.gradle is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dexterous.genero15"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.1.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.flavienlaurent.discrollview:library:0.0.2@aar'
}
```

This problem does't occur in my ant other app on play.
How can i solve this problem.

Comment: Does your AndroidManifest.xml specify anything?

Comment: no manifest contains only permission application and activity tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by the `discrollview` library. As you can see [here](https://github.com/flavienlaurent/discrollview/blob/master/lib/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml) the `AndroidManifest.xml` of the library has specified the `maxSdkVersion`:

```
<manifest
    package="com.flavienlaurent.discrollview.lib"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-sdk
        android:maxSdkVersion="19"
        android:minSdkVersion="14"/>

</manifest>
```

There is already a pull request that aims to fix the issue:
https://github.com/flavienlaurent/discrollview/pull/9

Comment: if we mention uses-sdk in our manifest then i suppose it will override discrollview's manifest uses-sdk

Comment: To override discrollview's manifest you need to specify `maxSdkVersion` in your `AndroidManifest` or `build.gradle`, add `uses-sdk` in your manifest is not enough. If you add `maxSdkVersion` you need to update your app every time there will be a new version of android. I do not think is an acceptable solution. If you don't want to wait that the pull request will be merged you can clone the repo, remove the `maxSdkVersion` from `AndroidManifest`, rebuild the library and use the generated aar.